Sizing and installing a post for a heavy swing gate?
I built a fence out of some reclaimed wood for a themed party in my back yard. We put it up to hide some of the plumbing and electrical gear on the side of the house.

Now I’m thinking I like it there, but I can’t have it covering up the gear. I’d like to put a metal post in the ground on the left and hinge it to allow access.
But I don’t know how to size the post or how to properly install it. The fence is quite heavy and close to 7' long. I tried finding a calculator or paper describing how estimate things like depth and hole diameter needed for a given torque load, but can’t find the necessary search terms.
The fence itself is quite rigid, with cross members and diagonals screwed into many of the vertical members.

Are you opposed to the non-hinge end having a wheel to lighten the load on the hinge side?

I thought about it, but it will run over a mulched area (walk-on bark) and would have to be a bit fat tire to avoid dragging it everywhere. Might be okay, as I don't expect to open it often, but it would be nice if it was entirely cantilevered.

Not an engineer and I can't find a calculator for this purpose, so I would probably  greatly overbuild it. I would probably make a 3x3x3 hole, place a 8' long 6" square tube of steel in it vertically, and fill with concrete. Again, not an engineer, so that might not be strong enough, but it seems like it would be for a single pole

How much access do you really need?  Like are you accessing the plumbing and electrical gear every day?  Once a year, or even less?  If the latter, do you really even need a gate—i.e. couldn't you simply have a bolt-on fastening system that you remove when you need to access?  Perhaps even something as simple as two pipes in the ground, with respective pins strapped to the fence, where you can just lift the pins out of the pipes to remove the fence for access.

A 7 foot long fence that is very heavy by your own admittance, would take quite a stout post to allow swing without substantial dip.  If you do not want the wheel, as UESean suggested, I would consider cutting the fence in half and making 2 gates that could hang off of 4x4 PT posts

@Huesmann It's for emergencies, more than anything, that it must be easy to access.

@Rick sounds to me like all you really need is a couple of posts driven into the ground, with a wire loop on each end of the "fence" to loop over each post.  When you need access, you flip the loop over the post and drag the thing out of the way (or just lay it down).  If the bottom of the fence being on the ground is a concern, put a brick/rock under each end to put it in the air.

That may be "all i really need," but it's not what I want.
